# Appending textbox to a div in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I created a div and a textbox using the following code

```
     var left_div = dojo.create('div', {
        id: 'left_div'
    }, child.borderContainer.domNode, 'first');

    child.borderContainer.clientName = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
        name:           'clientName',
        placeHolder:    'client name'
    });
```

Now, I have to append the clientName to the left div.

Comment: You can use [dojo.place](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/place)

Answer (score 2):

If clientName  is a widget you can use

```
widget.placeAt(parentNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
child.borderContainer.clientName = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
        name:           'clientName',
        placeHolder:    'client name'
}, left_div);
```

The second parameter for a widget constructor is usually the dom node to place the widget at.  From the [API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox):

> Usage:
>   var foo = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox(/* Object? */ params, /* DomNode|String */ srcNodeRef);